# How do I create a customized 'portfolio' or group of apps based on survey answers?

Tags: android, api, app-store

So I am currently working with Figma and designing my app to then create it using Bravostudio app. I want my users to take a survey and then a customized list of apps will be presented to them. How do I go about doing this?

I initially thought I could use a spreadsheet-based API - or create a database using google sheets and then turn this into an API to connect the responses to the list of apps. But not sure if this is even feasible.

Any help would be much appreciated! :D